# node.js+mongoose - Is single rest endpoint enough to update a document with nested arrays?

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

I'm developing a REST api using node.js + mongoose. I have a model which has few nested arrays within it. I have a put endpoint to update the document. However to add an object into the sub-array, do i need a separate endpoint or is there a way to use the same put endpoint? `

```
companyName: String,
city: String,
pincode: Number,
managers: [{
    name: String,
    dob: Date,
    gender: String,         
    highestEducation: String,
    email: String,
    phoneNumbers: [{phoneNumber: Number}],
}],`
```

I have an endpoint ../api/customer for updating the document. It replaces the existing document with the json that im supplying. So, if i want to add a manager (not replace the existing manager), do i need a seperate endpoint just for this? What is the optimized solution?

Comment: did you find any answer for your problem?

Comment: I fetched the document and manipulated the object and then updated the new document back. I didn't find a better way to insert a child node.